# Unable to use multi target loss function in pytorch python

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch, loss-function

I am unable to use loss function for a multi label classification in pytorch
This is my loss function:

```
 def loss(self,pred,y_true):
    pred = torch.tensor(pred)
    y_true = torch.tensor(y_true)
    loss = nn.NLLLoss()(torch.log(pred), y_true)   
    return loss
```

On trying to get loss:

```
model.loss(model(xtrain),ytrain)
```

It shows an error:

```
RuntimeError: 1D target tensor expected, multi-target not supported
```

I have also tried it with cross_entropy:

```
F.cross_entropy
```

but this error still shows up, is there an inbuilt loss in pytorch for multi_label classification

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a builtin to compute the multi-label classification cross-entropy. [`F.nll_loss`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.functional.nll_loss.html#torch.nn.functional.nll_loss) and [`F.cross_entropy`](https://pytorch.org/cppdocs/api/function_namespacetorch_1_1nn_1_1functional_1a29daa086ce1ac3cd9f80676f81701944.html) are for single-label tasks only (that's why it requires dense labels). However, you can implement it yourself.

- If `pred` contains your output logits then you need to extract the probability distribution and apply the negative log likelihood. This is the *softmax cross-entropy loss* with:

  ```
  >>> -torch.sum(F.log_softmax(pred, dim=1) * labels, dim=1)
  ```
- If each output component are independent from each other, then apply the sigmoid on the logits and consider each one as `0/1` classification task with the negative log-likelihood. This is the *sigmoid cross-entropy* loss:

  ```
  >>> act = torch.sigmoid(pred)
  >>> y_true*-torch.log(act) + (1-y_true)*-torch.log(1-act)
  ```